# Unable to Import CSV to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am working on project where i have to make a report but due to heavy nature to raw dumps i am using access i can use access decently but i want to automate my manual task like import multiple files into table. for your refence i am not that great in VBA but i can do rnd and all stuff to get result or else last hope Stack overflow so below is my code everything is working fine but data is not imported in table but i can see row counts are proper so where is data is do not know please help and if possible can you guide me to short the coding as i am taking long road to code and as for error i am attaching pic of it how it looks.

thank you in advance !!![image]

My Code:-

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()


Dim Path As String
Dim SFC1, SFC2, SFQ3, SFQ4, SFQ5, SFQ6, SFC7, SFC8, SFC9, SFC10, SFC11, SFC12 As Variant
Dim SFG1, SFG2, SFG3, SFG4, SFG5, SFG6, SFG7, SFG8, SFG9 As Variant

Path = "C:\Users\Kunal.Khaire\Desktop\POD KPI Access\Raw\"

SFC1 = "13_Nulceus.csv"
SFC2 = "1_Mastersheet_Cisco.csv"
SFQ3 = "5_Overall_Performance_(2).csv"
SFQ4 = "6_Overall_Performance_(3).csv"
SFQ5 = "7_Overall_Performance_(4).csv"
SFQ6 = "8_Overall_Performance_(5).csv"
SFC7 = "9_OB_Calls_not_Tagged.csv"
SFC8 = "4_Quiz_Level.csv"
SFC9 = "2_Toggle_Count.csv"
SFC10 = "3_Agent_Disconnection.csv"
SFC11 = "11_Call_Not_Answered.csv"
SFC12 = "10_LB_Tagged_Dump.csv"
SFG1 = "APR Raw - Genesys.csv"
SFG2 = "Day-Wise Agent Level.csv"
SFG3 = "Overall Tagging Summary Data.csv"
SFG4 = "Genesys - CSAT by Date.csv"
SFG5 = "9_OB_Calls_not_Tagged (1).csv"
SFG6 = "2_Toggle_Count (1).csv"
SFG7 = "3_Agent_Disconnection (1).csv"
SFG8 = "11_Call_Not_Answered (1).csv"
SFG9 = "10_LB_Tagged_Dump (1).csv"



DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Nucleus", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFC1), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Master_Cisco", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFC2), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True


DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Quality_1", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFQ3), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Quality_2", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFQ4), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Quality_3", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFQ5), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="Quality_4", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFQ6), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                    TableName:="C_OBcallnottagged", _
                    FileName:=(Path & SFC7), _
                    HasFieldNames:=True



MsgBox "Importing of CSV are done !!!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: What encoding are the csv files ?

Comment: i download them from Tableau software download -> crosstab -> file download as CSV

i checked i guess its Unicode Text (.*txt)

Comment: crosstab makes me suspicous that there may be a shape problem. 
 have you tried all the following to get some perspective?  See if you can manually import the data with the tools under the external data tab.  most likely you will have to do the job in pieces.  Even then Access dosen't give you access to the resulting VBA but Excel does.  Next try manually importing the data into Excel and find the resulting VBA for some hints.  Also, it is easy to both export from Excel to Access or import from excel to Access.  Excel is better at importing.  if Excel works, automate if from Access.

Comment: Open the smallest file in a text editor like Notepad++ and check it is comma delimited and not tab.